# how can i fix my "Date Tab" in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, date, tabs, phpmyadmin

I made a date tab for my database on phpmyadmin, however whenever something is submitted into the database, the date is submitted as "00.00.00" how can i fix this so the date is automatically submitted as the current date ?

Comment: do you mean date column?

Comment: yes, how do i fix it ?:D

Comment: how do you insert data into db?

Comment: this is the mysql i used "ALTER TABLE  `users` ADD  `Date` DATE NOT NULL AFTER  `id` ;"

Comment: this query do not insert data into db, this statement add column to db

Answer (score 2):

like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `XXXXX` CHANGE `YOUR_DATE` `YOUR_DATE` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

this is described in details:  [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

for mysql 5.6.5+ you can use datetime and related functions like `now()` : [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Comment: sorry, but you really need to be more descriptive than that.

Comment: i made a Date column in phpmyadmin using  this sql "ALTER TABLE users ADD Date DATE NOT NULL AFTER id;" ...... but whenever something is submitted into the database the date appears as "00.00.00" i want the date to be automatically submitted as the current date..

Comment: DATE cant be default current TIMESTAMP, youu need to make it TIMESTAMP